# socket.setEncoding() is treated as unresolved by PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm

I'm trying to figure out why PhpStorm 11 treats `setEncoding()` method as unresolved. I have Node.js plugin installed and core libraries enabled. Other methods are treated as resolved. The problem just with `setEncoding()` one.

Here is the simplest code example:

```js
var net = require('net');
var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.setEncoding('ascii');
```

I'm new to Node.js, but I'm guessing it's because `setEncoding()` function is somehow inherited from `Readable stream interface`. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

So, the question is how to force PhpStorm to "see" that function?

Comment: a lot of IDEs, and even the chrome console, don't like to fully execute the `new ` part to iterate the instance methods because doing so could have side-effects. so, if it's not on the constructor.prototype, it probably cannot be known ahead of time without potentially-harmful execution or some hint...

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for that answer.  It's good to know a the real reason why WebStorm has the same issue (setEncoding marked as "unresolved" yet it is a valid function at runtime).  You should consider making it a full-fledged answer.  I'm not the author of the above SO post so I could not mark it as accepted, but I'd certainly vote for it.